# How to find out which style(s) is applied to the control?

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a huge XAML theme with multiple control templates and styles. I need to find out which styles from this list are being applied to which of my controls. I see that the style of my control has changed, but I can't find the source template/style for that change. For example, I have a Grid and I see that the background has changed, but I can't find the the templates/styles that have that Grid as its TargetType with any of that Grid's parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Snoop tool](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) that can show you all your layout hierarchy and if element's attribute was set locally or inherited.